# Why does multiprocessing use only a single core after I import numpy?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, multiprocessing, blas

I am not sure whether this counts more as an OS issue, but I thought I would ask here in case anyone has some insight from the Python end of things.

I've been trying to parallelise a CPU-heavy `for` loop using `joblib`, but I find that instead of each worker process being assigned to a different core, I end up with all of them being assigned to the same core and no performance gain.

Here's a very trivial example...

```
from joblib import Parallel,delayed
import numpy as np

def testfunc(data):
    # some very boneheaded CPU work
    for nn in xrange(1000):
        for ii in data[0,:]:
            for jj in data[1,:]:
                ii*jj

def run(niter=10):
    data = (np.random.randn(2,100) for ii in xrange(niter))
    pool = Parallel(n_jobs=-1,verbose=1,pre_dispatch='all')
    results = pool(delayed(testfunc)(dd) for dd in data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

...and here's what I see in `htop` while this script is running:

[image: htop]

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 (3.5.0-26) on a laptop with 4 cores. Clearly `joblib.Parallel` is spawning separate processes for the different workers, but is there any way that I can make these processes execute on different cores?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168014/both-multiprocessing-map-and-joblib-use-only-1-cpu-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-10 - no answers there I am afraid, but it sounds like the same issue.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905264/python-multiprocessing-utilizes-only-one-core

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592018/multiprocessing-pool-processes-locked-to-a-single-core

Comment: Is this still an issue? I'm attempting to recreate this with Python 3.7 and importing numpy with multiprocessing.Pool(), and it's using all the threads (as it should). Just want to ensure that this has been fixed.

Comment: Is this the same issue? https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html#avoiding-over-subscription-of-cpu-resources  "Some third-party libraries – e.g. the BLAS runtime used by numpy – internally manage a thread-pool to perform their computations. … joblib tells supported third-party libraries to use a limited number of threads in workers managed by the 'loky' backend … Since joblib 0.14, it is also possible to programmatically override the default number of threads using the inner_max_num_threads argument of the parallel_backend function "

Answer (score 169, accepted):

After some more googling I found the answer [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue17038).

It turns out that certain Python modules (`numpy`, `scipy`, `tables`, `pandas`, `skimage`...) mess with core affinity on import. As far as I can tell, this problem seems to be specifically caused by them linking against multithreaded OpenBLAS libraries.

A workaround is to reset the task affinity using

```
os.system("taskset -p 0xff %d" % os.getpid())
```

With this line pasted in after the module imports, my example now runs on all cores:

[image: htop_workaround]

My experience so far has been that this doesn't seem to have any negative effect on `numpy`'s performance, although this is probably machine- and task-specific .

### Update:

There are also two ways to disable the CPU affinity-resetting behaviour of OpenBLAS itself. At run-time you can use the environment variable `OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE` (or `GOTOBLAS_MAIN_FREE`), for example

```
OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE=1 python myscript.py
```

Or alternatively, if you're compiling OpenBLAS from source you can permanently disable it at build-time by editing the `Makefile.rule` to contain the line

```
NO_AFFINITY=1
```

Comment: Thank, your solution solved the problem. One question, I have the same code but run differently on tow different machine. Both machines are Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, python 2.7, but only one have this issue. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Both machines have OpenBLAS (build with OpenMPI).

Comment: Old thread, but in case anyone else finds this issue, I had the exact problem and it was indeed related to the OpenBLAS libraries. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537716/importing-scipy-breaks-multiprocessing-support-in-python/23546547) for two possible workarounds and some related discussion.

Comment: Another way to set cpu affinity is to [use `psutil`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2241047/1959808).

Comment: I see this is for Python 2.7, is this fixed in Python 3.4?

Comment: @JHG It's an issue with OpenBLAS rather than Python, so I can't see any reason why the Python version would make a difference

Comment: @ali_m thank you, I see in Python issue version 2.7 then I need to be sure about it, thank you very much

Comment: I had a similar issue, but I had to call `os.system("taskset -p 0xff %d" % os.getpid())` inside the equivalent of `testfunc` to utilize more than a single core.

Comment: I think it's better to add flag `a` to apply affinity to all threads: `os.system("taskset -ap 0xff %d" % os.getpid())`

Comment: How can we do this ( os.system("taskset -p 0xff %d" % os.getpid()) ) in C++?

Answer (score 35):

Python 3 now exposes the [methods](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.sched_setaffinity) to directly set the affinity

```
>>> import os
>>> os.sched_getaffinity(0)
{0, 1, 2, 3}
>>> os.sched_setaffinity(0, {1, 3})
>>> os.sched_getaffinity(0)
{1, 3}
>>> x = {i for i in range(10)}
>>> x
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
>>> os.sched_setaffinity(0, x)
>>> os.sched_getaffinity(0)
{0, 1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Error > AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'sched_getaffinity' , Python 3.6

Comment: @Paddy From the linked documentation: _They are only available on some Unix platforms._

Comment: I have same problem but I have integrate this same line at the top os.system("taskset -p 0xff %d" % os.getpid()) but its not uses all cpu

Comment: I had the same problem on a cluster. Any python process run on a computing node would only use 1 core even though my code was in principle able to use more cores and even though I had requested ~20 cores. For me adding import os and os.sched_setaffinity(0,range(1000)) to my python code solved the problem.

Answer (score 15):

This appears to be a common problem with Python on Ubuntu, and is not specific to `joblib`:

- [Both multiprocessing.map and joblib use only 1 cpu after upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10 to 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168014/both-multiprocessing-map-and-joblib-use-only-1-cpu-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-10)
- [Python multiprocessing utilizes only one core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905264/python-multiprocessing-utilizes-only-one-core)
- [multiprocessing.Pool processes locked to a single core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592018/multiprocessing-pool-processes-locked-to-a-single-core)

I would suggest experimenting with CPU affinity ([`taskset`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/taskset.1.html)).

Comment: `Python on Ubuntu` This implies it's working without trouble on Windows and other OS. Is it?