# Install f2py with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, fortran, osx-mavericks, f2py

I need to call routines from Fortran modules within Python. I did it with `f2py` and `python2.7`. It worked pretty well.

Now, I have to use it with `python3` but `f2py` does not seem to be compatible with `python3`.

I see that some people use a version called `f2py3`, but it is neither available through `pip`, not through macports (I am using a Mac). Also, [python3+numpy+f2py seem to be already integrated in Fedora](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python3-numpy-f2py).

Does anyone have managed to use `f2py3` (or its equivalent) with `python3` on a Mac? If not, what alternate solution do you propose to link Fortran libraries with `python3`?

Comment: I'm interested in this also.  FYI, your Fedora link above returns no results when I try it but I get some info just searching for 'f2py' via your link.

Comment: I fixed the broken link. It should point on the download pages of the RPM resource for python3-numpy-f2py.

Comment: yeah, works now.  thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you can use [ctypes](/questions/tagged/ctypes) and [fortran-iso-c-binding](/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding) to call Fortran routines without relying on f2py. The downside of this approach is that you need to specify the interfaces yourself.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263879/speeding-up-element-wise-array-multiplication-in-python/19458585#19458585) I posted on SO some time ago.

Comment: Very interesting because f2py does not seem to be maintained anymore (maybe I am wrong?). The problem is that I need to use a lot of old fortran codes. Refactoring interfaces is not an easy task and can generate errors. But for sure, I'll use you suggestion for new codes.

Comment: Well, for old code you could use compiler options to influence the generated function names (e.g. [`-fno-underscoring` for `gfortran`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html)) and try to call the routines from python directly (without the ISO_C_Bindings). Then all the work would need to be done on the Python side. Note that this is (in general) not portable, and depends on the compiler used!

Answer (score 2):

[f2py comes with numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/usage.html) and based on [this January 2020 activity on github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/73d8ec888378fc9c8358ba4b88b93f2a48669c31), it seems clear that f2py is currently maintained.