# make: f2py: No such file or directory

Tags: python, makefile, f2py

I am running Mac OS X 10.10. I have some python code I have inherited. I need to run "make" in a certain directory, because I get a warning when I run my python script along the lines of `WARNING: failed to import test1lib. Please run make in /this/directory/` So I go to that directory where I find the following files:

```
 Makefile   __init__.py __init__.pyc    foo.py  foo.pyc foo_code.f  foolib.f
```

So I run `$ make`

but I get the following error:

```
f2py -c foolib.f -m foolib
make: f2py: No such file or directory
make: *** [foolib.so] Error 1
```

Running `which f2py` returns `/usr/local/bin/f2py` so its not like I don't have f2py, but why is my terminal expecting `f2py` to be a directory? What can I do so that I can run make on this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *have* `f2py`, then it's either not on the search `PATH`, or it has not been made executable.

I don't know if you are on Linux or Windows. Try to execute f2py manually and see if it starts. If not, try to locate it, and see where it is installed.

If you *can* start it from the command line, then show us the Makefile around where the command `f2py` is located.

EDIT: Ok... I'm suspecting that f2py is actually a Python script, and it has a shebang line (first line starts with #!) which calls for a python version you don't have. In my system, f2py start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

which calls python2.7.x... If you have python3, then f2py may not find it. Do you start Python with the `python3` command?

Note: It seems like `f2py` doesn't come for Python3 ('f2py3' or so).

Note: The error message you mention can come from a wrong [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line at the start of `f2py` (the shebang is the first line of the `f2py` executable - which is just a Python script). Normally it is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or maybe

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

if you compiled Python yourself. If it's neither of these, start suspecting. Maybe `f2py` was installed by some confused tutorial or demo.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean just typing `f2py` in the terminal? If so I get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/f2py: /Users/travis/build/MacPython/numpy-wheels/venv/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` Im running OS X btw

Comment: I edited the reply above... f2py does not seem to come for Python3. Here's a link to more discussion on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000857/install-f2py-with-python3

Comment: Just typing 'python' start python? Try `python -V` that should print the version

Comment: Yes, it is python 2.7.6

Comment: Indeed you are correct about the shebang line- in mine it is set to /Users/travis/build/MacPython/numpy-wheels/venv/bin/python which I don't understand. Should it be changed to /usr/bin/python?

Comment: When I do this it seems to work! Why on earth would my shebang line have been changed from the default? I certainly have not changed it! Could you also explain how you drew the conclusion that the shebang line was calling for a version of python that I don't have? Im trying to learn about these things so that I can become better at solving these issues in the future! Happy to accept your answer

Comment: Well, with the /usr/bin shebang you are using the system's Python, while with the large one, you try to call a Python in a virtual environment in you own directory. Which may (or may not) be the same version (and may not exist anymore). Try (from a terminal) calling `/Users/travis/build/MacPython/numpy-wheels/venv/bin/python -V` (by the way - that probably comes from a tutorial for numpy)