# Passing arrays between Python and Fortran using ctypes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fortran, ctypes

How should I convert a ctypes pointer back to a numpy array? I am a beginner in both python and fortran - apologies in advance if this is trivial.

Consider the code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(np.arange(6)) + 0.5
y = x.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
```

I have taken a numpy array 'x' and converted it into a form suitable for passing into a fortran subroutine as an array 'y'. However, how should I do the reverse operation?

[Q1] Is y is a ctypes pointer? Python says it is <**main**.LP_c_double at 0x7ff7186178c8>. What does this mean?

[Q2] Starting from y, how can I obtain x, given that I know how long the array x is? I tried:

```
ctypes.cast(y, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)).contents.value
```

This returns the first element of the array. However, trying to access the next elements using the following failed:

```
ctypes.cast(y, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)).contents.value
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should not need to convert a double pointer to numpy array. Keep a reference to the original numpy array.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263879/speeding-up-element-wise-array-multiplication-in-python/19458585#19458585) for an example that realizes this.

Comment: The comments are correct. It all works now.