# How to properly Forward the dropout layer

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I created the following deep network with dropout layers like below:

```
class QNet_dropout(nn.Module):

    """
        A MLP with 2 hidden layer and dropout

        observation_dim (int): number of observation features
        action_dim (int): Dimension of each action
        seed (int): Random seed
    """

    def __init__(self, observation_dim, action_dim, seed):
        super(QNet_dropout, self).__init__()
        self.seed = torch.manual_seed(seed)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(observation_dim, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc4 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(64, action_dim)

    def forward(self, observations):
        """
           Forward propagation of neural network

        """

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(observations))
        x = F.linear(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.linear(self.fc4(x))
        x = self.fc5(x)
        return x
```

However, when I tried to run the code, I got the following errors:

```
/home/workspace/QNetworks.py in forward(self, observations)
     90 
     91         x = F.relu(self.fc1(observations))
---> 92         x = F.linear(self.fc2(x))
     93         x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
     94         x = F.linear(self.fc4(x))

TypeError: linear() missing 1 required positional argument: 'weight'
```

It seems like I didn't properly use/forward the dropout layer. What should be the correct way to do the Forward for the dropout layer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F.linear() function used incorrectly. You should use your stated linear function instead of torch.nn.functional. The dropout layer should be after Relu. You can call Relu function from torch.nn.functional.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

class QNet_dropout(nn.Module):

    """
        A MLP with 2 hidden layer and dropout

        observation_dim (int): number of observation features
        action_dim (int): Dimension of each action
        seed (int): Random seed
    """

    def __init__(self, observation_dim, action_dim, seed):
        super(QNet_dropout, self).__init__()
        self.seed = torch.manual_seed(seed)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(observation_dim, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc4 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(64, action_dim)

    def forward(self, observations):
        """
           Forward propagation of neural network

        """
        x = self.fc2(F.relu(self.fc1(observations)))
        x = self.fc4(F.relu(self.fc3(x)))
        x = self.fc5(x)
        return x

observation_dim = 512
model = QNet_dropout(observation_dim, 10, 512)
batch_size = 8
inpt  = torch.rand(batch_size, observation_dim)
output = model(inpt)
print ("output shape: ", output.shape)
```

Comment: Sir may I draw your attention to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344611/how-can-take-advantage-of-multiprocessing-and-multithreading-in-deep-learning-us), you may help!