# How to limit GPU memory use in TF Slim?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

When training using TF Slim's train_image_classifier.py I would like to tell Slim to only allocate what GPU memory it needs, rather than allocating all the memory.

Were I using straight up TF and not Slim I could say this:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Or even just this to put a hard cap on GPU memory use:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

How can I tell Slim the same thing(s)?

My comprehension fail is that Slim seems to use it's own loop and I can't find docs on the nitty gritty of configuring the loop. So, even if someone could point me to good Slim docs that'd be fantastic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `allow_growth` option via the `session_config` parameter that is passed to the `train` method as follow:

```
session_config = tf.ConfigProto()
session_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
slim.learning.train(..., session_config=session_config)
```

See [tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py#L615](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py#L615) and [tensorflow #5530](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5530).

Comment: Oops. Thanks indeed. That seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @SherloxFR since you're into this topic , may I draw your attention to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344611/how-can-take-advantage-of-multiprocessing-and-multithreading-in-deep-learning-us?) with **bounty**.

Comment: @Mario you absolutely can

Comment: @SherloxFR it would be great if you can guide me. thanks for your quick consideration.