# multiprocessing pool map incredibly slow running a Monte Carlo ensemble of python simulations

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, montecarlo

I have a python code that runs a 2D diffusion simulation for a set of parameters.  I need to run the code many times, O(1000), like a Monte Carlo approach, using different parameter settings each time.  In order to do this more quickly I want to use all the cores on my machine (or cluster), so that each core runs one instance of the code.

In the past I have done this successfully for *serial* fortran codes by writing a python wrapper that then used multiprocessing map (or starmap in the case of multiple arguments) to call the fortan code in an ensemble of simulations.  It works very nicely in that you loop over the 1000 simulations, and the python wrapper farms out a new integration to a core as soon as it becomes free after completing a previous integration.

However, now when I set this up to do the same to run multiple instances of my  python (instead of fortran) code, I find it is incredibly slow, much slower than simply running the code 1000 times in serial on a single core.  Using the system monitor I see that one core is working at a time, and it never goes above 10-20% load, while of course I expected to see N cores running near 100% (as is the case when I farm out fortran jobs).

I thought it might be a write issue, and so I checked the code carefully to ensure that all plotting is switched off, and in fact there is *no* file/disk access at all, I now merely have one print statement at the end to print out a final diagnostic.

The structure of my code is like this

I have the main python code in **toy_diffusion_2d.py** which has a single arg of a dictionary with the run parameters in it:

```
def main(arg)
loop over timesteps:
    calculation simulation over a large-grid
print the result statistic
```

And then I wrote a "wrapper" script, where I import the main simulation code and try to run it in parallel:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,cpu_count
import toy_diffusion_2d

# dummy list of arguments
par1=[1,2,3]
par2=[4,5,6]

# make a list of dictionaries to loop over, 3x3=9 simulations in all.
arglist=[{"par1":p1,"par2":p2} for p1 in par1 for p2 in par2] 

ncore=min(len(arglist),int(cpu_count()))
with Pool(processes=ncore) as p:
    p.map(toy_diffusion_2d.main,arglist)
```

The above is a shorter paraphrased example, my actual codes are longer, so I have placed them here:

Main code: http://clima-dods.ictp.it/Users/tompkins/files/toy_diffusion_2d.py

You can run this with the default values like this:

```
python3 toy_diffusion_2d.py
```

Wrapper script: http://clima-dods.ictp.it/Users/tompkins/files/toy_diffusion_loop.py

You can run a 4 member ensemble like this:

```
python3 toy_diffusion_loop.py --diffK=[33000,37500] --tau_sub=[20,30]
```

(note that the final stat is slightly different each run, even with the same values as the model is stochastic, a version of the stochastic allen-cahn equations in case any one is interested, but uses a stupid explicit solver on the diffusion term).

As I said, the second parallel code works, but as I say it is reeeeeallly slow... like it is constantly gating.

I also tried using starmap, but that was not any different, it is almost like the desktop only allows one python interpreter to run at a time...?  I spent hours on it, I'm almost at the point to rewrite the code in Fortran. I'm sure I'm just doing something really stupid to prevent parallel execution.

EDIT(1): this problem is occurring on
4.15.0-112-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux, with Python 3.6.9

In response to the comments, in fact I also find it runs fine on my MAC laptop...

EDIT(2): so it seems my question was a bit of a duplicate of several other postings, apologies!  As well as the useful links provided by Pavel, I also found this page very helpful: [Importing scipy breaks multiprocessing support in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537716/importing-scipy-breaks-multiprocessing-support-in-python/23546547)  I'll edit in the solution below to the accepted answer.

Comment: This is indeed strange. Can you try changing the name of the method to something other than `main()` just in case its messing up the interpreter in some way?
Also, will it be possible to get the full code of simulation so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: ok, the main->new name didn't help, I added the links to the full code, thanks for the interest...

Comment: The multiprocessing module is clearly not the good tool for scientific computing (especially for array crunching). Prefer using Numba's `@njit` for that with `parallel=True`+`prange`.

Comment: python is admittedly not the right language to use for fast number crunching, but that is a completely seperate issue. I should still be able to run the program 8 times on 8 seperate cores and each core should run the code with the same performance as a single integration on a single core. Instead I get one core working at 10% efficiency while the other 7 sit idle. If I use the same wrapper to run a serial fortran code 8 times, all cores work at 100% efficiency. In fact the ensemble approach is "embarrassingly parallel" in theory.

Comment: @AdrianTompkins please specify your platform and python version whenever possible.

Comment: @Pavel - yes you are right, sorry, now added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample you provide works just fine on my MacOS Catalina 10.15.6. I can guess you're using some Linux distributive, where, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15641148/9632441), it can be the case that numpy import meddles with core affinity due to being linked with OpenBLAS library.

If your Unix supports scheduler interface, something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31370840/9632441) will work:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.sched_setaffinity(0, set(range(cpu_count)))
```

Another question that has a good explanation of this problem [is found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537716/importing-scipy-breaks-multiprocessing-support-in-python/23546547) and the solution suggested is this:

```
os.system('taskset -cp 0-%d %s' % (ncore, os.getpid()))
```

inserted right before the multiprocessing call.

Comment: thanks so much... This pointed me to the other pages I hadn't found, the soln:         os.system('taskset -cp 0-%d %s' % (ncore, os.getpid())) right before the mutiprocessing call worked for me.

Comment: If this solution was helpful, consider either to edit your question to include it or edit my answer. This will help other people struggling with the same problem to find the answer quicker.