# Multiprocessing Pool worse performance on chunks

Tags: python, multithreading, image-resizing, pool, chunks

I have some strange behavior with Python Multiprocessing Pool performance. In the following code, `data` is an ndarray of millions of images to be resized, and `chunks_list` is chunks of `data`. I use `pool = Pool(14)`. The function `resize_images` resizes a group of images at once, while `resize_image` resizes a signle image.
The following code:

```
res = [pool.apply_async(resize_image, args=[img]).get() for img in data]
```

is faster than this code:

```
chunks_list = [data[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size)]
res = [pool.apply_async(resize_images, args=[imgs]).get() for imgs in chunks_list]
```

Why is that? I expected the opposite to be true, because the first code will assign many 'tiny' processes to the pool of CPU's. But chunks will produce less assignations.
Is there more efficient way to achieve what I want? (GPU maybe?)

Comment: If the images are large you will waste a lot of time simply moving them between processes

Comment: @BlackBear This is why I did it in chunks, but was surprised that it's slower.

Comment: @BlackBear Please note that the function resize_images resizes group of images at once unlike resize_image that resize a single image.

Comment: My point was that chunks are larger, so the benefits of processing more of them at once are offset by the cost of copying more images around (but I'm just speculating). Try with shared memory maybe?

Comment: Good point. But how can I try shared memory ? I'm still new to Multiprocessing Pool.

Comment: I've never did that myself, maybe you can get away with https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes or https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639779/why-does-multiprocessing-use-only-a-single-core-after-i-import-numpy

Answer (score -1):

```
pool.map(preprocess_images, [imgs for imgs in chunks])
```

would do the job faster than both.