# Importing modules results in attribute error

Tags: python-3.x

In a python script, I tried importing both Bokeh and Seaborn, but both times received an error message.

This was done using anaconda, with another python script running in another terminal.

```py
import csv
import seaborn


x = []
y = []

with open('main.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    count = 1
    for row in plots:
        if count % 2 == 1:
            x.append(int(row[0]))
            y.append(int(row[1]))
        count += 1

seaborn.scatterplot(x, y)
```

Resulting in the following error message:

```
  File "graphinganomalies.py", line 2, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 345, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 171, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scipy.misc import doccer
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    from scipy.interpolate._pade import pade as _pade
    from .interpolate import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .interpnd import _ndim_coords_from_arrays
  File "interpnd.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.interpolate.interpnd
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from .ckdtree import *
  File "ckdtree.pyx", line 22, in init scipy.spatial.ckdtree
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Programs\multiprocessing.py", line 2, in <module>
    len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'sched_getaffinity'
```

Comment: Maybe [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538153/python-3-6-0-os-module-does-not-have-sched-getaffinity-method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.6.0: 'os' module does not have 'sched\_getaffinity' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538153/python-3-6-0-os-module-does-not-have-sched-getaffinity-method)

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler functions, including `sched_getaffinity()`, are not available on Windows:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#interface-to-the-scheduler

> These functions control how a process is allocated CPU time by the operating system. **They are only available on some Unix platforms.** For more detailed information, consult your Unix manpages.

Comment: Thank you! Will it work without the scheduler once the background script is finished running?