# Alternatives to os.sched_getaffinity for macOS

Tags: python, operating-system, python-os

Python's [`os.cpu_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.cpu_count) suggests using `len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))`.  However, this is not available on my Mac:

```py
>>> len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'sched_getaffinity'
```

From [Interface to the scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#interface-to-the-scheduler):

> They are only available on some Unix platforms.

Is there a good alternative (preference to built-in solutions) to `os.sched_getaffinity` for macOS?

Here is my short-term workaround:

```py
import multiprocessing
import os

def _get_core_count() -> int:
    try:
        # NOTE: only available on some Unix platforms
        return len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    except AttributeError:
        return multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

Comment: this suggests it is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658331/python-3-on-macos-how-to-set-process-affinity