# Getting numpy to run in parallel

Tags: python, r, numpy, parallel-processing, reticulate

I'm trying to use the [scanorama](https://github.com/brianhie/scanorama) package in R and am having some troubles with the parallelization. The readme of the scanorama package links to [this](https://roman-kh.github.io/numpy-multicore/) set of instructions for how to make sure numpy is using multiple cpus. My situation is a little different because I'm using a miniconda installation of python, but I tried to adapt this.

First, I created the `test.py` script that is listed in the above link and I ran it. When I run top to check it, I see:

[image]

Which indicates to me that it's NOT using multiple cpus. I don't have (or am not aware of the location of) the `dist-packages` referenced in that link, all I can find is `/home/lab/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core`, which contains:

```
_multiarray_tests.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Running `ldd` on both of those give me:

```
ldd _multiarray_tests.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd0bfb9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6d5831c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6d5870d000)
    
ldd _multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff5a5a8000)
    libcblas.so.3 => /home/lab/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/../../../../libcblas.so.3 (0x00007f9eb1179000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9eb0ddb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9eb0bbc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9eb07cb000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9eb1a4e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9eb05c7000)
```

Which doesn't appear to have any sort of link to openBLAS. I installed openBLAS via conda following [this link](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/openblas). Additionally, I tried to re-install numpy using the conda-forge version (which [this link](https://numpy.org/install/#numpy-packages--accelerated-linear-algebra-libraries) says should use openBLAS).

In python, if I check the numpy configuration, I get:

```
Python 3.7.10 (default, Jun  4 2021, 14:48:32)
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.show_config()
blas_info:
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/lab/miniconda3/lib']
    include_dirs = ['/home/lab/miniconda3/include']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/lab/miniconda3/lib']
    include_dirs = ['/home/lab/miniconda3/include']
    language = c
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/lab/miniconda3/lib']
    language = f77
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/lab/miniconda3/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/lab/miniconda3/include']
```

Which I'm not entirely sure how to interpret. I can see that there is information regarding blas, but neither `/home/lab/miniconda3/lib` nor `/home/lab/miniconda3/include` contain any of the four libraries indicated above.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639779/why-does-multiprocessing-use-only-a-single-core-after-i-import-numpy) post and [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue17038#msg180663) about making sure the cpu affinities aren't overwritten. Running through those, however, it appears that all of the cpus ARE available to be used:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> p = psutil.Process()
>>> p.cpu_affinity()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
>>> all_cpus = list(range(psutil.cpu_count()))
>>> p.cpu_affinity(all_cpus)
>>> p.cpu_affinity()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

But if I run the above and then run:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random_sample((size, size))
b = np.random.random_sample((size, size))
n = np.dot(a,b)
```

in the same session and check top, I'm still seeing 100% CPU usage and a small amount of memory usage.

The final thing I tried was to use python multiprocessing as described in [this link](https://urban-institute.medium.com/using-multiprocessing-to-make-python-code-faster-23ea5ef996ba). Here is how it looks in R:

```
# Python module loading in R
library(reticulate)
scanorama <- import("scanorama")
mp <- import("multiprocessing")
pool <- mp$Pool()

# Read in data (list of matrices and list of genes, as described in scanorama usage)
assaylist <- readRDS("./assaylist.rds")
genelist <- readRDS("./genelist.rds")

# Run the scanorama command from within pool$map
integrated.corrected.data <- pool$map(scanorama$correct(assaylist, genelist, return_dense = T, return_dimred = T), range(0,23))
```

Which still gives similar `top` results:

[image]

I know this isn't the cleanest/most straightforward question due to the interfacing between R and python, but wanted to put this out there to see if anyone had a similar experience or has any tips to point me in the right direction of figuring this out. I appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Comment: `But if I run the above and then run:` What did you define `size` to be in this example? Numpy won't parallelize small matrix multiplications, because the overhead involved in creating multiple threads is too high. `size = 10000` should be safe.

Comment: The numpy install docs have a special note about installing from conda: https://numpy.org/install/#numpy-packages--accelerated-linear-algebra-libraries "In the conda-forge channel, NumPy is built against a dummy “BLAS” package. When a user installs NumPy from conda-forge, that BLAS package then gets installed together with the actual library - this defaults to OpenBLAS, but it can also be MKL (from the defaults channel), or even BLIS or *reference BLAS*." I suspect you're getting reference BLAS.

Comment: Could you try installing numpy from the default conda channel rather than conda forge? I think that might be the simplest solution.